# При создании столбца на основании других столбцов, возникает ошибка: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),..."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть DataFrame
Пример:

```
    y   s   step_vol
0   1   10  90
1   0   20  87
2   1   15  1
3   2   80  7
4   3   90  90
5   4   1   54
6   0   10  12
7   3   90  12
8   1   65  90
9   0   12  143
```

Я хочу создать еще один столбец `y_f`, который будет иметь значение `1`, если `(data['y']>0) & (data['s']>limit) & (data['step_vol']>limit)`, где `limit` - определенное значение

Для этого пишу функцию:

```
def get_y(data, limit=50):
    if (data['y']>0) & (data['s']>limit) & (data['step_vol']>limit):
        data['y_f'] = 1
    else:
        data['y_f'] = 0
    return data['y_f']
```

Применяю функцию:

```
get_y(df, limit=50)
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Как ее исправить?

Comment: data['y'] это Series объект, т.е. вы берете перечисление данных по **y**, и сравниваете его с 0

Comment: Надо тогда либо iterrows() брать, либо брать уже готовую pandas функцию, которая меняет значения по шаблону.. Не помню как называется, простите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопроc решен 
Надо вот так делать:

```
def filter_size(row):
    if (row['y'] >1) & (row['s']>50) & (row['step_vol']>50):
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

df['y_f'] = df.apply(filter_size, axis=1)
```

Спасибо всем за ответы)

Comment: Вы ответ-то поправьте. а то у вас функция определена с одним названием, а в appy - другая

Answer (score 2):

Простой и быстрый (векторизированный) вариант решения - преобразовать результат условия из булевого в целый (8-битный `int`) столбец:

```
data['y_f'] = (  (data['y']>0) 
               & (data['s']>limit) 
               & (data['step_vol']>limit)).astype('int8')
```

или более короткий вариант:

```
data['y_f'] = data.eval("y > 0 and s > @limit and step_vol > @limit").astype('int8')
```

результат:

```
In [84]: data
Out[84]:
   y   s  step_vol  y_f
0  1  10        90    0
1  0  20        87    0
2  1  15         1    0
3  2  80         7    0
4  3  90        90    1
5  4   1        54    0
6  0  10        12    0
7  3  90        12    0
8  1  65        90    1
9  0  12       143    0
```

---

PS `df.apply(..., axis=1)` - один из самых медленных вариантов решения - "под капотом" это завуалированный `for` цикл. Его стоит использовать если других, более быстрых вариантов, нет